# Where to place Model / Property Permissions

Tags: security, openapi

This question pertains to OpenAPI 3.0.0

Have a need to specify Create, Read, Update and Delete permissions as pertains to models and properties.

To be specific, some of our permissions are defined on the models/properties and although there is a correlation with the controller method / operations, they are not the same.

This is for internal use to communicate to clients but would still like to know if a pattern exists.

Two options I have considered are:

- Add an `x-permissions` to each applicable `Components Object` and be done
- Define User permissions in a `Security Scheme Object` and reference them from the appropriate `Security Requirement Object`

Specs to reference:

- [Security Requirement Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#security-requirement-object)
- [Security Scheme Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#security-scheme-object)
- [Specification Extensions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#specification-extensions)